# Recommendation Sytem without rating data

Tags: cluster-analysis, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to figure out how to solve a task given to me by a customer.

The customer is a company that distributes books to final shops (books shop). It would like to know in which way it can give a service to its sales division starting from the assumpition that we can identify cluster of shops that are similar in terms of customers they sell to, and then similar in sub-market demand.

The data which the recommendation system relies on is data on the features of the single book (author, genre, date of pubblication, etc...) and the historical data of the past book orders made by the shops to the company.

Is it possible, with this data, to setup a recommendation system? If yes, which approach should I use?

Thanks for any helps,

Filippo.

Comment: Typo alert: it's **recommendation** with *one* "c" and *two* "m" - not the other way around

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks